# Withlatestfrom not emitting data from async observable

Tags: javascript, promise, functional-programming, rxjs, reactive

as you can see from the snippet below, 
`withLatestFrom` never completes if a promise is passed over.

```js
const { combineLatest, range } = rxjs;
const { withLatestFrom } = rxjs.operators;

const a$ = range(1, 5);
const b$ = Promise.resolve('never');

a$.pipe(
  withLatestFrom(b$),
).subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.2/rxjs.umd.js" integrity="sha256-mNXCdYv896VtdKYTBWgurbyH+p9uDUgWE4sYjRnB5dM=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

it works just fine if `const b$ = of(1);`

---

The documentation is not clear about this behaviour, 
any hint?

Comment: That's a timing issue that has to do with the event loop. `from(p())` just emits one step to late for your `s1.pipe(withLatestFrom(s2b))` to catch it. If you delay the emission of `s1`, even by 0, `const s1 = of(1).pipe(delay(0))` it will be pushed to the next loop where `s2b` emits its value and you get your desired output `[1, 'b']`. https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-epnbko

Comment: When you say its a 'timing issue', do you mean it's an issue with my implementation (I'm assuming it's this) or it's a known bug / quirk with rxjs?

If the former, I don't fully understand why it's an issue. I thought `withLatestFrom` would emit when the observable completes. And since it's an observable it shouldn't matter _when_ the observable completes.

Comment: By timing issue I mean it has to do with the way the browser queues and processes tasks and microtasks. Of course it also has to do with how `withLatestFrom` works. In your last line `s1` gets subscribed to and emits but `s2b` hasn't emitted anything yet (the promise hasn't resolved yet) so `withLatestFrom(s2b)` won't emit anything as there is no latest value from `s2b`. `withLatestFrom` won't wait for its inner observable `s2b` to emit.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't realize you were talking about the JS event loop, I was reading your comment as something related to the way rxjs observables work. Now knowing that `withLatestFrom` will not wait for an emit from an observable clears up where I was thinking about this incorrectly. Many thanks.

Comment: Not sure if the operator I added to my answer is a better solution, but it does what I wan't with a promise, and if long lived observable is passed in using `shareReplay(1)` it would work for that is well. Can this be improved upon / is it a terrible idea?

Answer (score 0):

Per fridoo, I had an incorrect understanding of how `withLatestFrom` was working. `withLatestFrom` will not wait for its source to emit. Delaying the source observable or waiting for the async operation by other means (`combineLatest`) such will cause the observable to emit properly.

Comment: Why don't you use `combineLatest(s1, s2b)`? If `s2b` is a Promise it will only emit once anyway so the fact that `combineLatest` emits whenever `s2b` emits shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: I want to use `withLatestFrom` on promises and long lived observables that reach out to APIs asynchronously in the project I am working on. I only included the promise in the code to be concise, because I believed the root cause for both use cases to be answered by the example with the promise. You're right though, if it were just a promise I was worried about `combineLatest` would work just fine. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way and this should be in my humble opinion a operator, maybe even replace the withLatestFrom.

```js
this.selectedItemsFiltered$.pipe(
  switchMap(selectedItemsFiltered => {//TODO: Make out of this a combineLatestFrom operator
    return this.isInitialOnSelectedItemsChangeSkipped$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(isInitialOnSelectedItemsChangeSkipped => [selectedItemsFiltered, isInitialOnSelectedItemsChangeSkipped] as [string[], boolean])
    )
  })
...
```

This code will only trigger if the parent selectedItemsFiltered$ emits, then it will switchMap to the other observable, since this is a switchMap it will await the other Observable, same scenario would have been possible with multiple observables you would just have to combineLatest them inside switchMap.